# jQuery Object Serialize

Tags: jquery, serialization

What is the difference between this?

```
$("form").serialize();
```

and this?

```
var theForm = $("form");
$(theForm[0]).serialize();
```

How do you get the second sample to serialize like the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var theForm = $("form");
theForm.eq(0).serialize();
```

Answer (score 2):

First one selects all forms and serializes all form fields.

Second one selects form fields from **FIRST** form and serializes them

Comment: the problem is the second one doesn't serialize the first form.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use in one line:

> $("form:first").serialize();